# Translate at fixed rate while key pressed

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm trying to have an `ImageView` move inside a pane as long as a key is pressed. Because I want the animation to be as smooth as possible, I figured the JavaFX animation toolkit would be my best option, but I cannot find out how to properly control the speed of the animation. This was my idea:

```
ImageView image;
TranslateTransition translate;

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
   image = new ImageView("file:D:\\test.jpg");
   image.setFocusTraversable(true);

   AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane(image);
   pane.setOnKeyPressed(event -> translate.play());
   pane.setOnKeyReleased(event -> translate.stop());

   translate = new TranslateTransition();
   translate.setOnFinished(event -> translate.playFromStart());
   translate.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1.0));
   translate.setByX(20.0);
   translate.setNode(image);

   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
   primaryStage.show();
}
```

Which works as I expected, aside from a very noticeable pause between each cycle of animation. The reason why I was going with this approach was to be able to control the speed of the `ImageView`, here for instance a constant speed of 20 pixels per second.

It would seem more appropriate to use an `AnimationTimer`, but it is my understanding that this timer is dependent on the frame rate at which the stage is being refreshed, which could vary between computers, in turn producing varying animation speed.

My question is two-fold. First, is it possible to modify my code in order to remove the delay between one cycle finishing and the next starting? Second, what better approach can you suggest?

The problem being that I cannot simply loop the animation using `Animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE)` because when it loops the image will start back from its original position.

Comment: One fix is to use `translate.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)`. Note that the `Animation` classes probably all hook into the same mechanism that `AnimationTimer` does and are updated once per frame. If you used `AnimationTimer` you can utilize the argument of the `handle` method which is the timestamp of the current frame. Compare it to the previous frame and move the node the necessary amount based on the time difference.

Comment: It does the trick indeed thank you. Now, I'm not sure that this method is dependent on the frame rate of the application. I suppose that `Animation.play()` is able to interpolate the correct coordinate outside of the render loop, which wouldn't slow it but merely drop late frames, but it's only a supposition. If it does, it ends up being in my opinion easier to use, otherwise using an `AnimationTimer` the way you propose it should work.

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835   and http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops. Very good resources.